# How to mask a "crop" a multi dimensional numpy array by N dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

say I have an array a, that can be N dimensional, but for simplicities sake let's say its:

```
a = np.array([[0,1,2],
             [3,4,5]])
```

I also have a mask or crop(I dont know the proper term) that is has the length of N, so in this case something like:

```
b = [1,2]
```

How can I "crop" the array so its:

```
a = a[:b]
```

which would slice a the same as:

```
a = a[:1,:2]
```

but would work no matter the value of N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `slice` notation -

```
a[tuple([slice(None,bi) for bi in b])]
```

Or with its shorthand `np.s_` -

```
a[tuple([np.s_[:bi] for bi in b])]
```